# SQlite 3 Ruby can only add one column of data

Tags: ruby, sqlite

This is driving me insane!! I have a number of arrays which I want to put into an SQLite database. Each time I run my code it only puts in the first array in and then all the rest get "Null" I can change the order of the arrays but regardless of the array the first one always goes in but the rest don't

Here is my code, to set up the database

```
require 'sqlite3'

DBNAME= 'resultsdb.sqlite'
File.delete(DBNAME) if File.exists?DBNAME 

$db= SQLite3::Database.new(DBNAME)
$db.execute("Create TABLE althete (date, event, pos, array1, array2, array3, agecat, gender, genderposition, array4, array5, array6)")
```

Here is the code to insert the arrays,

```
$positions.each do |position|
  $db.execute("INSERT INTO althete (pos) VALUES ('#{position}')")
end 

$events.each do |event|
  $db.execute("INSERT INTO althete (array1) VALUES ('#{event}')")
end
```

And I have similar statements for the ten other arrays that I would like to go into the same table.

Sorry, my code is probably very sloppy as I am still learning ruby, any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is the table called `results` or `althete`? What do `$positions` and `$events` look like? What are you expecting the table to look like when you're done?

Comment: Sorry yes the table should be athlete. Both $positions and $event are an array of string. The $positions array in effect at the moment is just 1,2,3,4,5,6........150. $event is another array of strings, with dates in it. I am hoping to have a table with the headers date, event, pos, array1, array2, array3, agecat, gender, genderposition, array4, array5, array6. And then each of the arrays will populate the columns, for each for example the column headed by "pos" will contain the $positions array, so the first array entry will be on row 1, second on row 2 etc. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So you want to loop through all the `$positions`, `$event`, ... arrays at once and build rows in your table using one element from each array on each iteration?